# Finding fixed points the circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+(2g-9)y+4=0$ passes through

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

I am supposed to find two pairs of points the circle meeting the following constraints passes through.

> A circle cutting $x^2+y^2=4$ orthogonally and having its center on the line $2x-2y+9=0$ passes through two fixed points. Find them.

---

**My Attempt**

Let the circle be $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ where $g,f,c\in \mathbb{R}$. Since the circle cuts $x^2+y^2=4$ orthogonally. So by using the condition for orthogonality we get that $c=4$. Now using the fact that the centre of the circle lies on $2x-2y+9=0$, we have $-2g+2f+9=0$. So the equation of the circle can be written as $x^2+y^2+2gx+(2g-9)y+4=0$.

---

I do not know how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated. Kindly also inform about the techniques for finding fixed points for any curve. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done well so far. 
Now, write your final expression as 
$$x^2+y^2-9y+4 + g(2x+2y)=0$$
If you observe, this expression represents a family of circles which pass through the point of intersection of the circle $x^2+y^2-9y+4 =0$
and the line $x+y=0$.
Therefore the fixed points are obtained when you solve the equations of the line and circle simultaneously which is quite simply obtained by plugging $x=-y$ in the equation of the circle

Answer (score 2):

Your equation can be rewritten as:
$$
x^2+y^2+2g(x+y)-9y+4=0.
$$
As we seek solutions valid for any value of $g$, that is possible only if $x+y=0$. Plug then $y=-x$ in the equation to find the solutions.